Sequence of $R$-modules is exact if and only if its induced $\operatorname{Hom}$-sequence is exact
Apologies if this is a copy; I didn't find any relevant questions on here.
I am studying for my exam and came across a Proposition which states the following:
"Let $R$ be a (commutative) ring. Let $u_1: M_1 \to M_2$ and $u_2: M_2 \to M_3$ be $R$-module homomorphisms. Then $$M_1 \to M_2 \to M_3 \to 0$$ is exact if and only if $$0 \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(M_3,N) \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(M_2,N) \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(M_1,N)$$ is exact for any $R$-module $N$".
Here the arrows in the induced sequence is given by right composition with the relevant $u_i$, i.e. $\big(\operatorname{Hom}_R(M_3,N) \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(M_2,N): f \mapsto f \circ u_2\big)$ and $\big(\operatorname{Hom}_R(M_2,N) \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(M_1,N): f \mapsto f \circ u_1\big)$
I am having trouble proving the "if" part, i.e. if the $\operatorname{Hom}$ sequence is exact, then the original sequence is also exact. I have tried to write out the relevant definitions but I am drawing a blank. Any help is appreciated!


Something that I have tried is the following. From exactness at $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M_2,N)$, we know that for any $R$-module morphism $f: M_3 \to N$, we have $f \circ u_2 \circ u_1 = 0$. Maybe for some "nice" choice for $f$, this tells us something about $u_2 \circ u_1 = 0$? But also, this only implies that $\operatorname{im}(u_1) \subset \operatorname{ker}(u_2)$ and not the other way around, so one would have to go about proving that separately.

Assume
$$0 \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(M_3,N) \stackrel{-\circ u_2}{\longrightarrow} \operatorname{Hom}_R(M_2,N) \stackrel{-\circ u_1}{\longrightarrow} \operatorname{Hom}_R(M_1,N)$$
is exact for any $N$.
In particular, for any morphisms $g,h\colon M_3\to N$, we have that $g\circ u_2 = h\circ u_2$ implies $g=h$; that is, $u_2$ is cancellable on the right, and hence an epimorphism. Since epimorphisms in the category of $R$-$\mathsf{Mod}$ are precisely the surjective maps (consider cokernels), it follows that $u_2$ is surjective.
Next we need to show that $\mathrm{Im}(u_1) = \ker(u_2)$.
To prove that $\mathrm{Im}(u_1)\subseteq\ker(u_2)$, it is enough to pick some $N$ and $f\colon M_3\to N$ that is one-to-one. So for example take $N=M_3$ and $f=\mathrm{id}_{M_3}$. Then we know that $f\circ u_2\circ u_1=0$, and hence that $u_2\circ u_1=0$. Thus, $\mathrm{Im}(u_1)\subseteq \ker(u_2)$.
So far we have used exactness at $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M_3,N)$, and that the composition $$\mathrm{Hom}_R(M_3,N)\to\mathrm{Hom}_R(M_2,N)\to\mathrm{Hom}_{R}(M_1,N)$$
is the zero map; we have not yet used the full assumption of exactness at $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M_2,N)$, which suggests that we will need to use it in order to conclude the final inclusion. This exactness tells us that if $f\colon M_2\to N$ is such that $f\circ u_1=0$, then $f=g\circ u_2$ for some $g\colon M_3\to N$.
To prove that $\ker(u_2)\subseteq\mathrm{Im}(u_1)$, take $N$ to be the cokernel of $u_1$, and $f\colon M_2\to M_2/\mathrm{Im}(u_1)$ be the canonical projection. Then $f\circ u_1=0$, so there exists $g\colon M_3\to M_2/\mathrm{Im}(u_1)$ such that $f=g\circ u_2$. In particular, if $x\in\ker(u_2)$, then $f(x)=g(u_2(x)) = 0$, so $\ker(u_2)\subseteq\ker(f)$. But $\ker(f)=\mathrm{Im}(u_1)$, which proves that $\ker(u_2)\subseteq\mathrm{Im}(u_1)$, as required.
